# Send alert if due date is exceeded

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, alert

I want to send an alert to my coworkers when the due date of the issue from a list is exceeded.

We use SharePoint 2013.

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a SharePoint Designer workflow to send the alert email like the below:
[image]

Then create a Information Management Policy-retention rule to trigger the workflow when [Due Date]+ 0 days:
[image]

It no needs to run the action everyday.

Comment: It's perfect, thank you so much

Comment: if it helps you, please remember to accept it as answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Simple way: Use Retention policy in [Information Management Policy](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/introduction-to-information-management-policies-63a0b501-ba59-44b7-a35c-999f3be057b2) to run this workflow every day. you can set `Time Period` on due date. and trigger your simple designer workflow to send emails.

[image]

Comment: Hello and thank's for the answer i'm gonna try this and see if it works

Answer (score 1):

Please use the SP Workflow to achieve your requirement. I have shared the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer but i can't pause the workflow